# Best way get first word and rest of the words in a string in C#

Tags: c#, linq, string

In C#

```
var parameters =
    from line in parameterTextBox.Lines
    select new {name = line.Split(' ').First(), value = line.Split(' ').Skip(1)};
```

Is there a way to do this without having to split twice?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can store the split in a `let` clause

```
var parameters =
    from line in parameterTextBox.Lines
    let split = line.Split(' ')
    select new {name = split.First(), value = split.Skip(1)};
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure.

```
var parameters = from line in parameterTextBox.Lines
                 let words = line.Split(' ')
                 select new { name = words.First(), words.skip(1) };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string Str= "one all of the rest";
Match m = Regex.match(Str,"(\w*) (\w.*)");
string wordone = m.Groups[1];
string wordtwo = m.Groups[2];
```

Comment: This would be a better approach, since not only a whitespace can separate a word.

Comment: I would say linq is a different way of doing programming I use linq often but I never think that it looks clean. Though quite effective.  I have been using regex for years and is almost always my choice for text parsing

Comment: Group[0] is the whole match not the words.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> getParameters(string[] lines)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string pName = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
        string pVal = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
        results.Add(pName, pVal);
    }
    return results;
}
```